# R: create a nested list from a list of vectors

Tags: r, list, nested

I would like to create a nested list with a list of vector.
Each vector of the list contains 3 elements.
The idea is to use the first element of the vector as a key, the value will be a list which key will be the 2nd element of the vector and the value the 3rd element.

I tried:

```
input <- list()
input[[1]] <- c("V3", "c100", "s10")
input[[2]] <- c("V3", "c100", "s25")
input[[3]] <- c("V3", "c90", "s10")
input[[4]] <- c("V3", "c90", "s25")
input[[5]] <- c("V2V3", "c100", "s10")
input[[6]] <- c("V2V3", "c100", "s25")
input[[7]] <- c("V2V3", "c90", "s10")
input[[8]] <- c("V2V3", "c90", "s25")

lapply(input, function(x){
    list(x[1] <- list(x[2] <- x[3]))
})
```

I get:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "s10"



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "s25"
...
```

but I would like something like:

```
$V3
$V3$c100
$V3$c100[[1]]
[1] "s10"

$V3$c100[[2]]
[1] "s25"


$V3
$V3$c90
$V3$c90[[1]]
[1] "s10"

$V3$c90[[2]]
[1] "s25"


$V2V3
$V2V3$c100
$V2V3$c100[[1]]
[1] "s10"

$V2V3$c100[[2]]
[1] "s25"


$V2V3
$V2V3$c90
$V2V3$c90[[1]]
[1] "s10"

$V2V3$c90[[2]]
[1] "s25"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Nested list ≠ dictionary in Python!

Comment: You're right, I've corrected my text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way but using `data.table` does the trick:

```
require(data.table)

dt = data.table(x = sapply(input, '[', 1),
                y = sapply(input, '[', 2),
                z = sapply(input, '[', 3))

dt2 = dt[, {
  l1 = list()
  l1[[x]][[y]] = as.list(z)
  list(l1)
}, by = list(x, y)]

dt3 = dt2[, list({
  l2 = list()
  l2[[x]] = unlist(V1, recursive = FALSE)
  l2
}), by = x]

out = dt3[['V1']]
names(out) = dt3[['x']]

out
```